# ERROR "main class not found "

Tags: java

My java is work properly if without adding any classpath to system variable. When I add a classpath to system variable, I got a error show me "main class not found".

Is there any problem with my configuration? I have installed both JDK1.7.0_13 and JRE7. My develop environment is shell, I didn't use any IDE.

P.S. I wrote the following program on test.

```
 public class jdbc11{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
    try{
        System.out.println("hello");

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and system class path I set is 
JAVA_HOME\jre\lib      JAVA_HOME\lib       JAVE_HOME\jre\lib\ext

Comment: And what classpath did you set? How would you like us to approach solving your issue. Take a look at your question. Have you provided any useful information. Kindly add all the information that you think, YOU would have needed to solve this problem

Comment: Have you written public static void main(String[] args){} method in main class?

Comment: Rohit thank you for your comment. I have add new information below PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath could be gotten erroneous when changing the system classpath. In every case the normal way would be:

App.java:

```
package org.edison.pkg;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
...
```

Having a java source `x/y/myproject/src/java/org/edison/pkg/App.java`

Compiling to `x/y/myproject/target/classes/org/edison/pkg/App.class`

-cp gives the class path on the commandline.

Running:

```
x/y/myproject> java -cp ./target/classes org.edison.pkg.App
```

Comment: After a few hours of fighting, yes it works. I do exactly what you say, adding a package to my java source code file and relocate the file.Thank you

Comment: No package would mean root directory, but it is generally considered bad practice for non-throw-away projects, and a build tool like *maven* will provide by default packages.